# React sometimes not using updated source files

Tags: reactjs

Usually when I make a change in a source code file the server automatically updates. Though occasionally it does not, even if I reload the page, or even close the tab and load fresh from a new blank browser tab. I have to restart the server to finally see the change. I found this out upon changing a console.log message.

Is there a way to ensure that the server is using all of the latest source files without having to restart the server? (ya as I already mentioned usually it does this automatically, but at times it does not.)

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: Checkout this thread if so - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9904

Comment: Ya, I'm using create-react-app. Also using firebase and quill. Thanks for the link. This behavior rarely pops up so figuring out what triggers it isn't easy. I'll try to re-trace my steps if it happens again.